# HTML: XML data island won't link

Tags: html, xml

I can't get my htm file to link with my xml file, or if it is linking I can't get it to work.

This for a class I'm taking and I know data islands are practically extinct now, but that doesn't change my assignment.

So, I have the XML and the HTM, I have looked at 4 different sources and can't see anything wrong with my code that links the two but it doesn't seem to work and that goes for my whole body section as well. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Thanks!

HTM:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--NewsDisplay.htm -->
<xml id="newsInfo" src="News.xml"></xml>
<title>News Display</title>
<style>
body {background-color:rgb(255,255,192)}
#News_Title {font-family:Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:40pt}
#News_Author {font-family:Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15pt}
#News_Text {font-family:Ariel, Helvetica, sans-serif}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="News_Text"> S************* 12/12/14</div>
<div id="News_Title" datasrc="#newsInfo" datafld="Title"></div>
<div id="News_Author" datasrc="#newsInfo" datafld="Author"></div>
<div id="News_Text" datasrc="#newsInfo" datafld="Newsdata"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

XML

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<!--News.xml-->

<Information>
    <Title>Recognize the components of the Visual Basic Editor </Title>
    <Author>Garry Gibson </Author>
<Newsdata>
<![CDATA[
Visual Basic for Applications is an excellent built-in tool for customizing or
automating operations within the Microsoft Office application packages as well
as many non-Microsoft software packages. The Visual Basic Editor is actually a set of
three windows: the main, the Project Explorer and Properties windows. The main window
comprised of the title bar, menu bar and the Standard toolbar appears at the top of the
screen. The Properties window includes characteristics for each object controlling its 
appearance and behavior. Within the Project Explorer window is the Code window that is 
opened whenever VBA instructions called a procedure are entered as a block of code.
]]>

</Newsdata>
</Information>
```

Comment: Do you know that XML data islands are no longer supported in IE >= 10? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801224)

Comment: @KubaRakoczy yes but I'm using chrome and I tried IE8 so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: I tested in on BrowserStack under IE8 and it seems to work correctly. The only mistake I found is the duplication of the `News_Text` id.

Comment: @KubaRakoczy Made a mistake and didn't allow activex or something in IE8 and then I retried it and it worked, my bad. If you want you can have right answer

Comment: Nah, that's not necessary. Glad you figured it out :)